# labeling the plot frame automatically

Tags: plotting, labeling

```
parametersNV := {R = 2.5};   
parametersNV;   
diffeq = {u''''[x] + \[Alpha]*(x*u'''[x] + 3*u''[x]) + R*u[x]*u'''[x] - 
 R*u'[x]*u''[x] == 0};    
inicond = {u[0] == 0, u''[0] == 0, u[1] == 1, u'[1] == 0};    
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{diffeq, inicond}, {u}, {x, 0, 4}, {\[Alpha]}];
d1 = Evaluate[u[0.1]'[x] /. sol];    
framelbl := {{{"\[Theta](\[Zeta])",Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, {"\[Zeta]", parametersNV}}};
```

This is my code and i want to label my frame using the list parametersNV. The problem i am facing is that it only shows it value {2.5}. i want it to show R=2.5. i know i can achieve it by just enclosing is in " " and using in following command. The case i posted here is very simple. i am automating the system and would have to deal with many curves and parameters. So it would be good directly to use the aforementioned list.
Here is my try.

```
pic = Plot[{d1}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False,Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> Black,FrameLabel -> {{"\[Phi](\[Eta])",Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, {"\[Eta]", parametersNV}}, PlotLegends ->Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {"\[Lambda]=0.4", "\[Lambda]=-0.4"},LegendLayout -> "Column", LegendFunction -> "Frame",LegendMarkerSize -> {17, 1}], {0.84, 0.2}],FrameStyle -> Directive["Areal", 14]]
```

need it to be

```
pic = Plot[{d1}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False,Frame -> True,LabelStyle -> Black,FrameLabel -> {{"\[Phi](\[Eta])",Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, {"\[Eta]","need a lable here using framelbl saying R=2.5"}},PlotLegends ->Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {"\[Lambda]=0.4", "\[Lambda]=-0.4"},LegendLayout -> "Column", LegendFunction -> "Frame",LegendMarkerSize->{17, 1}], {0.84,0.2}],FrameStyle->Directive["Areal", 14]]
```

Comment: use `R = 2.5; parametersNV = HoldForm[R = 2.5];` or `R= 2.5; parametersNV = "R = 2.5";`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it would require typing it again. this is what i want to avoid. i will write every thing in a loop later. so need it automated.

Comment: does `parametersNV = Defer[R = 2.5];` work?

Comment: I would do sth like `parametersNV={"R="<>ToString[the value from outer source]}`

Comment: @ corey979 I am afraid it wont. i posted just one parameter R. In original code i have many and i want to avoid typing them again and again. this is the primary goal.@ kguler R needs to be evaluated for ParametricNdsolve, but for lalbel i need it unevaluated. i tired many things but in vain. at the moment i am just copy-pasting the values inside parametersNV to " " in Frame label command. but obviously it manual

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With no changes in the first 6 lines of your first code block,

```
pNV = OwnValues[parametersNV] /. RuleDelayed[x_, {y_}] :> HoldForm[y] /. {x_} :> x;

framelbl := {{"θ(ζ)", Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, {"ζ", pNV}};

Plot[{d1}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> Black, FrameLabel -> framelbl, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"λ = 0.4", "λ = -0.4"},
    LegendLayout -> "Column", LegendFunction -> "Frame",
    LegendMarkerSize -> {17, 1}], {0.84, 0.2}], FrameStyle -> Directive["Arial", 14]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A less convoluted approach is to change your second line to

```
parametersNV2 := HoldForm[R = 3.5]; ReleaseHold[parametersNV2];
```

and use

```
framelbl2 :=  {{"θ(ζ)", Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, {"ζ", parametersNV2}};
```

With the option setting `FrameLabel -> framelbl2` we get the same picture as above.

Using

```
parametersNV3 :=  HoldForm[{R = 2.5, otherparameters = {1, 2, 3}}]; 
ReleaseHold[parametersNV3];

framelbl3 :=  {{"θ(ζ)", Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, {"ζ", parametersNV3}};
```

we get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Updates:**

> How can we remove these `{ }` from last option?

Using `Composition[StringTrim[#, "{" | "}"] &, ToString][parametersNV3]` instead of `parametersNV3` in the definition of `framelbl3`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> ... some parameters had subscripts, i cant use them with trimming ...

```
parametersNV4 := HoldForm[Sequence[R = 2.5, otherparameters = {1, Subscript[a, 2], 3}]]; 
ReleaseHold[parametersNV4];
framelbl4 := {{"θ(ζ)", Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, 
  {"ζ", StringReplace[ToString[parametersNV4, StandardForm], "HoldForm[" | "]" -> ""]}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How can we remove these { } from last option? i tries first two; the first give HoldPattren n every think inside. the second one doesnt work with more than one parameters. the first and last can work if we could get rid of extra {} or Hold thingy. thank you very much by the way for your efforts,

Comment: @naveed, in the last example, you can trim the curly braces  using `Composition[StringTrim[#, "{" | "}"] &, ToString][parametersNV3]` and use it instead of `parametersNV3` in the definition of `framelbl3`.

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you again and again. trimming did the work but now a new problem :). some parameters had subscripts, i cant use them with trimming coz if i do things just get messed up and {} remains there and subscripts get displayed as separate variables.any way to fix that?

Comment: @naveed, does this work `parametersNV3 := 
 HoldForm[Sequence[R = 2.5, 
   otherparameters = {1, Subscript[a, 2], 
     3}]]; ReleaseHold[parametersNV3];
framelbl3 := {{"\[Theta](\[Zeta])", 
    Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, {"\[Zeta]", 
    StringReplace[ToString[parametersNV3, StandardForm], 
     "HoldForm[" | "]" -> ""]}};`?

Comment: Thank you v v much. that does the trick and finally i got what i wanted. @ everyone  "gratitude"

Comment: @naveed, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.